How to temporarily disable sorting in cxGrid while modifying data in For loop?
I have a cxGrid with one of the column sorted. The grid is not connected to a database. But if connected, the problem is the same.
When I iterate through visible rows and fill or modify data in that sorted column, the rows reorder and I can't modify each row. Half rows are skipped. The solution is to use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate, but in this case I don't see changes until all rows are processed, which may take a long time. And I want to see the progress.
If i do DataController.ClearSorting then the rows reorded before the loop start. Is there a way to just disable reordering and enable it after all rows are processed? So that I could change data and it didn't affect the rows order.
Actually, the same problem is with filtered records. When filtered only rows with non-empty  value in modified column and I set the value, the row disappears causing row skip in the For loop.
Or maybe the question is how else to iterate through visible and filtered rows while they are reordering.
var DrwView: TcxGridTableView;


//  DrwView.BeginUpdate;
//  DrwView.DataController.ClearSorting(True);
  DrwView.OnFocusedRecordChanged:=nil;

  for i:=0 to DrwView.DataController.FilteredRecordCount-1 do begin
    rec:=DrwView.DataController.FilteredRecordIndex[i];
    filename:=DrwView.DataController.GetValue(rec, DrwViewColumn1.Index);
    if FileExists(filename) then DrwView.DataController.SetValue(rec, DrwViewColumn2.Index, ExtractFileExt(filename));
    dwProgressBar1.Position:=i;
  end;
  DrwView.OnFocusedRecordChanged:=DrwViewFocusedRecordChanged;
//  DrwView.EndUpdate;

The sorted column is DrwViewColumn2, which is initially empty. This code skips half of the rows. When applied again, it fills a half of the remained rows and so on.
